# Background image in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For some odd reason background image is not showing in IE. I have tried using the full path to the image, using just background instead of background-image, using png, gif, jpg, using quotes and double quotes around the image path. Basically tried everything suggested on the net with regard of background image in IE

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 1008px;
margin: 0 auto; 
font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
font-size:14px;
line-height: 190%;
text-align:left;
text-decoration: italic;
background-image: url(../images/bgr_top.jpg), url(../images/bgr_bottom.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x;
background-position:center top, center bottom;
}
```

The only suspicion that I have is that I am using two images, one for the top and one for the bottom of the page.
Also read about a space after the closing bracket, but not sure if it is relevant as I am using background-repeat: on a different line.

Any other suggestions are very welcome :)

Comment: Have you had a look using ["F12 Developer Tools"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507(VS.85).aspx)? Check "Trace styles" and "Layout" for the `html` and `body` tags for specified and rendered height. Also check the "CSS" tab for any crossed out lines on those elements.

Comment: CSS does not have any crossed out lines. In the Trace Stiles it shows font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
font-size:14px;
line-height: 190%;

Comment: and for the Layout shows a graph with offset, margin, border, padding

Comment: And `width` or `height` on the layout tab are not `0`? PS, reading some comments for the answer below, I think they mean you should use: `background-image: url(../images/bgr_top.jpg);` without the comma, as it is not supported in lower IE versions to have more than 1 background specified. @ultraviol3tlux's suggestion is your best bet for IE8+ support.

Comment: width and height are 0. I know I can use only one background but the idea is to use two :) There is another option that work in IE8 that I implemented on many websites, but unfortunately I cannot do it on this one as the body width is 1008px and not 100%. Otherwise I will just use one background for the html and one for the body.

Comment: So `width` and `height` being `0` should be why there is nothing showing then. I notice you don't have a height specified at all (and I'm not sure if you have relative content inside `body`), maybe adding `height: 100%` to `html, body` might fix it then?

Comment: I just decider to use another approach... see in the end of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know how I fixed my issue. I have added and additional div which holds the whole website and then I have added the top image to the html and the bottom image to the body in the css.

```
html {
    background: url("../images/bgr_top.jpg");background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position:center top;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
background: url("../images/bgr_bottom.jpg"); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position:center bottom;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 190%;
    text-align:left;
     text-decoration: italic;

}

.main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1008px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-size:14px;
    line-height: 190%;
    text-align:left;
     text-decoration: italic;

}
```

**The Result**
I have now two backgrounds in all browsers including IE7,8,etc

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
background-image: url(../images/bgr_top.jpg), url(../images/bgr_bottom.jpg);
```

will only work in browsers which support css3 & hence only IE 9+

Best way to support all browsers would be to use separate entities for each background.

Comment: You could use psuedo elements on the root `<html>` tag to get the double background effect if desired, and that will work in IE8+ without having to add extra HTML.

Comment: could you add a fiddle or steps to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Silly question, but does your page have rendered height? If for some reason `<html>` and `<body>` have zero height, they wouldn't show backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

are they working on different browser? i would first check to see if the urls are correct and the image exist on them, open developer tools and see if the browser download them, also need to use only one image and see if you can see that, also IE 9 is not supporting css 3 it can cause the images not to showen

Comment: it is working in IE 10 an chrome. Also if I type the path to the background image in the IE, it opens it. I have read something about a problem with JPG 2000 but this isnt my case

Comment: IE10 doesn't support CSS3? [I think it does](http://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+10,ie+11,firefox+23,chrome+29).

Comment: I dont have IE 9, but with 8 I can open the image. and I am using the full path in the css.